Unable to print window ID out of the for-loop
I am trying to print my parent window id, but I am getting output as null.
Unable to understand where I made a mistake.


Getting output as null when I try to print it out of the for-loop. Anyone, please help me with this?

seeing "enter image description here" is a first sign of laziness, or "I do not care" :- /  Anyway Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

you have used ,parentwin' as a local variable in first 'if' block. It's scope will be limited to the 'if' block. Hence getting null.
solution- remove declaration of parentwin from if block.

Change declaration
String parentwin = driver.getWhindowHandle()

in if block to:
parentwin = driver.getWhindowHandle();

